# How to give bottom shadow to FragmentTabHost in android?

Tags: android, xml, fragment, android-tabhost, shadow

Hi I want shadow to my tabhost in my fragment. My XML code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried all solutions available on stackoverflow but it doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried Layer-list shadow in the background of the FragmentTabHost ?

Comment: Nope . How to do this ?

Comment: have you tried `android:elevation=""` this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using fragmenttabhost it is not possible to manipulate its view.

Answer (score 2):

[image]There is no such attribute in Android, to show a shadow. But possible ways to do it are:

1. Add a plain LinearLayout with grey color, over which add your actual layout, with margin at bottom  to 1 or 2 dp
2. Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout

Try this.. create   layout_shadow.xml   and put in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Apply to your layout like this

```
 android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
```

Final Layout of tab host

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

**Let me know if not work**

Comment: Nope its not working .It give box shadow to whole page .But i only want bottom shadow to tabs.

Comment: it work here perfectly if its not fit for 2dp   Just change  android:bottom="4dp"  attribute to 4dp or 10dp and check

Comment: try for LinerLayout than

Answer (score 0):

`Layer-list drawable` is one of the way to give shadow effect to views by setting in background.

Please follow this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Drawables) for creating different drawable for views and check the `View Box Shadows` mentioned in this link.

Comment: I just want bottom shadow .

Comment: Where is the link ?

Comment: @Mhandroid : Yes, you can set the bottom. It is explained there

Comment: This link is usefull for normal layouts but not for my tabs :(

Comment: Please check view box shadows under that link